# VW not working correctly in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

VW units are displaying strangely for me in IE9. For instance, a value of 10vw is enormous, taking up ~10 times the viewport width instead of a tenth. Setting the value to 0.1vw yields results closer to what is expected. What is strange is that I can find almost nothing on this issue, but I would have thought that if this is a real issue or incompatibility it would have been widely documented (and griped about). I'm using IE9 in a VM, so I don't know if that's the issue or not.

This is a jsfiddle I found that provides a simple case:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtvz5mty/

CSS:

```
#thisscales{
font-size:10vw;
width:40vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="thisscales">hai there!</div>
```

Has anyone dealt with this before? Is this a real issue? If so, what is a good work around? I'd like to get font-sizes and the positions of text elements to scale with the viewport (I'm doing animations and the positioning of the elements must be proportional).

Comment: Testing on IE11 set to IE9 rendering mode shows the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Adam IE9 rendering mode is no substitute for the real thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently not including this in the HTML was the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Adding it worked a charm. I will never be lazy and not include it again.

Comment: After some more research, I can't duplicate your findings. A doctype doesn't make a difference; as you can see in the fiddle, both the parent page and the output frame have proper doctypes. On my machine, the only thing that makes a difference is whether you display the page in an iframe or not. I goes wrong when used in an iframe. ([This page](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill/issues/45) also complains about the same issue, so it's not localised to my machine.)

Comment: I applied this to a page that was not in an iframe and it fixed the issue. It could be some combo of the virtual machine I was using, Windows 7, and IE9. Although I could probably wave a rubber chicken around the monitor and achieve the same results.

The only other thing that might explain it is that I also had the meta viewport tag shown in the answer below in the page.

Comment: OK, maybe there are other differences that can explain the result. Exact version of IE, settings, other installed software, display drivers, version of the virtualisation software, etc. The thing we can learn from this is if it works "here", that doesn't necessarily mean it works "over there". And that it's better to use only the most recent browsers. Oh well.

Comment: I think every dev would love to use the most recent browsers. IE9 has less than 2% of the market, but the client I'm working for (a global brand natch) has it installed standard on their systems and won't budge with it. Still, I'll take IE9 over IE6, which I've also had to accommodate in the last year.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a well-known bug in IE 9 and 10.

This webpage here describes a good way to fix it: [Here](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/09/24/fixing-cross-browser-issues-with-css3-viewport-units-in-ie9-and-safari-for-ios/)

And the Github Project for the fix is located: [Here](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill)

Comment: The buggy-fill addresses vmin and vmax specifically, for IE9, but no mention of vw for IE9 (there is for mobile safari, which is a different issue). What I'm mystified by is the near total lack of anything on the interwebs about this issue. Either my google-fu is lacking, or this isn't an actual bug. I just can't confirm the latter with the resources I have to hand.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `<head>` section of your html file. So now `vw` (viewport-width) will equals the `device-width` in whatever the browser you use (those which supports `vw`).

Comment: Doesn't make a difference here.